# java reflection casting issue

Tags: java, reflection

I wonder if you can see what is wrong with my code.

**First I have this class**

```
package de.daisi.async.infrastructure.component.event;
import static de.daisi.async.infrastructure.component.event.CType.*;

public class TemperatureEvent implements IEvent {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private CType cType = ONEP_ONEC;

public String toString(){
    return "TemperatureEvent";
}


public CType getcType() {
    return cType;
}
}
```

Via java reflection I want to get the CType value (ONEP_ONEC)

```
package de.daisi.async.infrastructure.comunicationtype;
import de.daisi.async.infrastructure.component.event.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class CheckComType {

public CType checkType(Class<? extends IEvent> eventClass) {
    System.out.println("Check communcationType: " + eventClass);

    CType cType = null;

    try {
        System.out.println("---In Try---");
        Class cls = (Class) eventClass;
        System.out.println("cls: " + cls);

        Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("getcType");
        System.out.println("method: " + method);
        Object instance = cls.newInstance();

        cType = (CType) method.invoke(instance);
        System.out.println("instance: " + instance);
        System.out.println("cType: " + cType);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cType;

}

public static void main(String... args){
    CheckComType type = new CheckComType();
    CType testType = type.checkType(TemperatureEvent.class);
    System.out.println("testType: " + testType);

}
```

}

**The testType result is null and I got a ClassCastException**

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   de.daisi.async.infrastructure.component.event.CType cannot be cast to
>   de.daisi.async.infrastructure.comunicationtype.CType at
>   de.daisi.async.infrastructure.comunicationtype.CheckComType.checkType
>   at de.daisi.async.infrastructure.comunicationtype.CheckComType.main

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What do your `import`s look like in `CheckComType` and `TemperatureEvent` ?

Comment: You have two CType classes in different packages - `de.daisi.async.infrastructure.component.event.CType` and `de.daisi.async.infrastructure.comunicationtype.CType`. Make sure you don't mix them. Unfortunately, it's hard to see as you didn't include the imports.

Comment: Dont put more information into comments. Update your question instead!

Comment: Because full class names is what counts. Packages are essentially namespaces, classes that belong to different packages are different classes even if their names are identical. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package

Comment: I just added the packages

Comment: but then, how the imports should be declared?

Comment: Is solved,  i had two CType classes, thank you for your observations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently have two different `CType` classes, one in the `de.daisi.async.infrastructure.component.event` package and the other in `de.daisi.async.infrastructure.comunicationtype`. Since you don't explicitly reference `de.daisi.async.infrastructure.component.event.CType` in `CheckComType`, the class from the same package (namely `de.daisi.async.infrastructure.comunicationtype.CType`) is used.

In Java, full class names is what counts. Packages are essentially namespaces, classes that belong to different packages are different classes even if their names are identical.

```
de.daisi.async.infrastructure.component.event.CType cType = null;

try {

    //...
    cType = (de.daisi.async.infrastructure.component.event.CType) method.invoke(instance);
}
```

and so on.

Or just explicitly `import de.daisi.async.infrastructure.component.event.CType` in `CheckComType` if you don't intend to use both `CType`'s in the same class.

Comment: Thank you! Now is solved, I didn't realize that i had two CType classes ... :)

Comment: Great! You can mark it as answered then. I hope this also answers your question (in a comment) about how the imports should be declared.